# Trying to start a .sh on boot

Tags: permissions, terminal, systemctl, autostart, minecraft

I try to start a `start.sh` file when the Server starts.

Some info:

- It's a headless vServer
- I tried `crontab` but that didn't work either
- My current approach is `systemctl` command
- When I login the user is root
- It's a Ubuntu server

Content of my `systemctl` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=MCServer Start
After=multi-user.target
 
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/mcs/start.sh
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Content of the `start.sh`:

```
screen -S minecraft java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar /home/mcs/server.jar
```

When I check the status after reboot the system replies with this:

```
● mcs.service - MCServer Start
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mcs.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-06-30 12:12:16 CEST; 32min ago
    Process: 700 ExecStart=/home/mcs/start.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 700 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jun 30 12:12:16 v25431 systemd[1]: Started MCServer Start.
Jun 30 12:12:16 v25431 systemd[700]: mcs.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Jun 30 12:12:16 v25431 systemd[700]: mcs.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/mcs/start.sh: Permission denied
Jun 30 12:12:16 v25431 systemd[1]: mcs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jun 30 12:12:16 v25431 systemd[1]: mcs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
root@v25431:~#
```

I see that I'm missing permission ... how do I fix that?

A little heads up... I'm pretty new to Linux so, explain it to me like I'm 5 or 80 years old ^^

Edit:

When I change the `systemctl` to:

```
[Unit]
Description=MCServer Start
After=multi-user.target
 
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=sh /home/mcs/start.sh
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the output changes to

```
● mcs.service - MCServer Start
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mcs.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-06-30 12:59:08 CEST; 22s ago
    Process: 1324 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh /home/mcs/start.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1324 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 30 12:59:08 v25431 systemd[1]: Started MCServer Start.
Jun 30 12:59:08 v25431 sh[1325]: Must be connected to a terminal.
Jun 30 12:59:08 v25431 systemd[1]: mcs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 30 12:59:08 v25431 systemd[1]: mcs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Requested Output:

```
root@v25431:~# ls -l /home/mcs/start.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72 Jun 29 23:39 /home/mcs/start.sh
```

Comment: yes i'v done that

Comment: Please include the output of `ls -l /home/mcs/start.sh` in your question

Comment: done, i edited it to the bottom of the question

Comment: The usual tool for running scripts at boot time is the rc-local service. Put your code in /etc/rc.local, add `#!/bin/bash`, make it executable and enable `rc-local.service`. However, your code fails because you use `screen`, which requires a terminal. I believe that options `-d -m` allow you to start `screen` without one.

Comment: @berndbausch 
- i dont have a file called rc.local in this directory, also the -d -m didn't work
|||   at Archemar 
-sry, i dont know what you mean 
-added #!/... in the start.sh, still does't work

Comment: If you don't have /etc/rc.local, you need to create it. But never mind - since your error is caused by `screen`, it won't make a difference whether you use rc.local or a different file. You first need to find out how to use `screen` without terminal, or launch your program without `screen`.

Comment: i think ill pass on the screen then ... thanks for your time eveyone

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about systemctl, but cron + Ubuntu has always worked fine for me. Please try this:

Type `crontab -e`, or `sudo crontab -e` (if your script should run as super user). Then you may be asked to choose which editor you prefer. Choose `nano`. Then append the following line:

```
@reboot cd /home/mcs/ && bash start.sh
```

Now save the file (*CTRL*+*o*, then *y*), exit (*CTRL*+*x*) and reboot. Please report if this works for you.

(Make sure to make your `start.sh` script executable by running `chmod +x /home/mcs/start.sh` once.)

EDIT: Also, of course, first make sure that your script runs as expected when launched manually. Only then proceed to the autostart stuff.

Comment: sadly didnt work, i will ditch the screen then it will run

Comment: If it will run, since your question was about starting a script at boot, please consider marking this as the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found the solution if someone has the same problem.

first i followed this guide: https://www.bennetrichter.de/anleitungen/minecraft-server-linux/ non germans use google translate...

after that i added the start.sh to crontab (`crontab -e`) like so:
`@reboot /home/minecraft/start.sh`

after reboot you can view the screen with `screen -r`

i have no idea why it works, but it does

Comment: @reboot  on crontab’s instruction is fired upon reboot.